# A problem on "identical()" function in R? How does "identical()" work for different types of objects?

Tags: r, integer, double, storage, notation

(reproducible example added)

I cannot grasp enough why the following is `FALSE` (I aware they are `double` and `integer` resp.):

```
identical(1, as.integer(1)) # FALSE
```

`?identical` reveals:

*num.eq:
logical indicating if (double and complex non-NA) numbers should be compared using == (‘equal’), or by bitwise comparison. The latter (non-default)
differentiates between -0 and +0.*

`sprintf("%.8190f", as.integer(1))` and `sprintf("%.8190f", 1)` return *exactly equal* bit pattern. So, I think that at least one of the following must return `TRUE`. But, I get `FALSE` in each of the following:

```
identical(1, as.integer(1), num.eq=TRUE) # FALSE
identical(1, as.integer(1), num.eq=FALSE) # FALSE
```

I consider like that now: If `sprintf` is a notation indicator, not the storage indicator, then this means `identical()` compares based on storage. i.e.
`identical(bitpattern1, bitpattern1bitpattern2)` returns `FALSE`. I could not find any other logical explanation to above `FALSE`/`FALSE` situation.

I do know that in both 32bit/64bit architecture of R, integers are stored as 32bit.

Comment: `identical(1, as.numeric("1"))` yields `TRUE`. It could be a starting point. Also, `identical(1L, as.integer("1"))` is `TRUE` as well

Comment: @Kots In both of your identical (...), you are comparing the same thing: "double1 vs double1" and "integer1 vs integer1". In my problem, "double1 vs integer1" is compared.

Comment: Then i guess you have your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not identical precisely because they have different types. If you look at the documentation for `identical` you'll find the example `identical(1, as.integer(1))` with the comment `## FALSE, stored as different types`. That's one clue. The R [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects) reminds us that:

> Single numbers, such as 4.2, and strings, such as "four point two" are still vectors, of length 1; *there are no more basic types* (emphasis mine).

So, basically everything is a vector with a type (that's also why `[1]` shows up every time R returns something). You can check this by explicitly creating a vector with length 1 by using `vector`, and then comparing it to `0`:

```r
x <- vector("double", 1)
identical(x, 0)
# [1] TRUE
```

That is to say, both `vector("double", 1)` and `0` output vectors of type "double" and length == 1.

`typeof` and `storage.mode` point to the same thing, so you're kind of right when you say "this means `identical()` compares based on storage". I don't think this necessarily means that "bit patterns" are being compared, although I suppose it's possible. See what happens when you change the storage mode using `storage.mode`:

```r
## Assign integer to x. This is really a vector length == 1.
x <- 1L

typeof(x)
# [1] "integer"

identical(x, 1L)
# [1] TRUE

## Now change the storage mode and compare again. 
storage.mode(x) <- "double"

typeof(x)
# [1] "double"

identical(x, 1L) # This is no longer TRUE.
# [1] FALSE

identical(x, 1.0) # But this is.
# [1] TRUE
```

One last note: The documentation for `identical` states that `num.eq` is a…

> logical indicating if (double and complex non-NA) numbers should be compared using == (‘equal’), or by bitwise comparison.

So, changing `num.eq` doesn't affect any comparison involving integers. Try the following:

```r
# Comparing integers with integers.
identical(+0L, -0L, num.eq = T) # TRUE
identical(+0L, -0L, num.eq = F) # TRUE

# Comparing integers with doubles.
identical(+0, -0L, num.eq = T) # FALSE
identical(+0, -0L, num.eq = F) # FALSE

# Comparing doubles with doubles.
identical(+0.0, -0.0, num.eq = T) # TRUE
identical(+0.0, -0.0, num.eq = F) # FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You systematically explained all I want.